# how to redirect jsp page to server ip address using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, wildfly

In my project, I'm using servlets to redirect another .jsp pages. When I'm working localhost redirect is running correctly.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String uname=request.getParameter("userName");
        String pword=request.getParameter("password");
        String decrypted=null;
        userSolrJava SJ = new userSolrJava();
        SolrDocumentList list;
        String Usererror=null;
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        try {
            list = SJ.getSolrList(uname);
            DecryptPassword dp=new DecryptPassword();
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                decrypted=dp.main("Bar12345Bar12345", "RandomInitVector",(String)list.get(i).getFieldValue("password"));
                System.out.println(decrypted);
                if(list!=null && 
                        list.get(i).getFieldValue("userName").equals(uname) && 
                        decrypted.equals(pword))
                {
                    out.println("Welcome, "+uname);
                    Cookie loginCookie=new Cookie("userName",uname);
                    loginCookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
                    response.addCookie(loginCookie);
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

                }
                /*else if(!list.get(i).getFieldValue("flag").equals("YES"))
                {
                    Usererror="Your account has not been approved, please contact your administrator!";
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("Usererror", Usererror);
                    response.sendRedirect("userLogin.jsp");
                }*/
                else
                {
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("userLogin.jsp");
                    Usererror="Either username or password is wrong.";
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("Usererror", Usererror);
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }

            }

        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

When I run my project with tomcat or wildfly server, the servlets are not redirect the other .jsp page correctly. When I'm pushing the login button, it must redirect to index.jsp but it stays stuck in servlet page and it gives me this in page

`Served at:E-Archive/` 
Why it's not working server side? I want to redirect it like this ip address 
`172.18.132.158:8080/E-Archive/index.jsp`

Comment: I suppose that new page you want to redirect is in a different host. if that so, you can't just put relative URL to redirect. You should put absolute URL with the host and port.

Comment: But at the end you are doing a `doGet` - where is that taking you?

Comment: I made it like this `String host=request.getRemoteHost(); response.sendRedirect(host+"/E-Archive/index.jsp");`. I want to ask one more question. How to write hostname in `<a href>` link??